# Realm Swift - filter objects using List properties (more than one)

Tags: ios, swift, realm

How can I filter objects using more than one property on the child objects.  So "find all parents with male children older than 10"

```
class Parent: Object {

   @objc dynamic var name: String?

   let children = List<Child>()
}
class Child: Object {

   @objc dynamic var name: String?
   @objc dynamic var gender: String?
   @objc dynamic var age: Int?

}
    let filtered = realm.objects(Parent.self).filter("ANY (children.name == %@ && children.gender == %@)", "some name", "male")
```

It doesn't seem like this is a valid query.

Or do I have to do something like this which strangely also seems to give the incorrect result - but I might need to do some more testing on this.

```
let filtered = realm.objects(Parent.self).filter("ANY children.name == %@", "some name").filter("ANY children.gender == %@", "male")
```

In the end it seems that first getting all children that match the criteria and then finding the parents of those children worked reliably.

```
let matchingChildren = realm.objects(Child.self).filter("name == %@ && gender == %@)", "some name", "male")

let parentsOfMatchingChildren = realm.objects(Parent.self).filter("ANY children IN %@", matchingChildren)
```

Comment: can you add ObjectsToFilter object here?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use `ANY` with a complicated expression in parenthesis like that. You need split the `ANY`:

```
ANY children.name == %@ && ANY children.age > %@
```

Also, `%@` is for objects (such as strings). For an integer like age, you need to use `%d`:

```
ANY children.name == %@ && ANY children.age > %d
```

Alternatively, you can use `SUBQUERY` as well:

```
SUBQUERY(children, $child, $child.name == %@).@count > 0 && SUBQUERY(children, $child, $child.age >%d).@count > 0
```

Comment: Thanks but splitting the ANY like that does not work because the LOGIC must be to find a child that has the NAME X AND whose AGE is > Y.   BTW in Swift everything is an object (Int, Double, String).

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald Keep in mind that `NSPredicate` (which realm uses under the hood) is an Obj-C API. But you are right about the `ANY` part. I was wrong. It should work if you split it into two filters, or use a `SUBQUERY`. I will update the answer later.